# Firebase Simulator blocking write, when I think it should be allowed by my rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm writing a simple Firebase app. All of the logic is now working, but I'm trying to write some security rules to at least stop someone messing up all my data.

I don't track users or authenticate them, my app is to be usable by anyone without a login.

I have a list of soccer players in this format:

```
Player
 -results
   -0
   -1
   -2
   -3
```

Each of the results has a field called `Points` which I want to be writable, but a field called `Name` which I do not want to be writable.

I have implemented the following rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read":true,

        "Player" : {
          "results": {
            "$results_id": {
              ".read":true,
            "Name":{
              ".read":true,
              ".write":false
              },

            "Points":{
              ".read":true,
              ".write":true,
              }


             }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But when use the simulator to write `{ "Points" : 2}` to `/Player/results/1` I get an error message:

```
Attempt to write {"Points":2} to /Player/results/1 with auth=null
    /
    /Player
    /Player/results
    /Player/results/1

No .write rule allowed the operation.
Write was denied.
```

I thought that `$record_id` was a wildcard that would match the ID, clearly I'm wrong, but could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like with read operations, where you need read permission at the level where you read, with write operations you need permission at the level where you write.

You're executing a write to `/Player/results/1`, which is not allowed.

You are allowed to write to `/Player/results/1/Points`. So if you change the operation to write `/Player/results/1/Points` with value `2` it will be allowed.

Comment: Thanks again, I think you helped me out with another query a couple of days ago. It's very cool that an engineer working on Firebase is helping people out. I migrated to Firebase when I found out parse was shutting down. I'm glad I found Firebase, I prefer it to parse, please keep up the good work!

Comment: Will do! The volume of questions has increased a lot though. So if you have a moment and know an answer, please help out! :-)